# Is it OK to store all valid instances of a parameterized class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class parametrized with a number, but only some values are in fact valid parameters. In order to hide implementation from user and to prevent invalid instantiating, I did this:

```
// foo.hpp
class IClass
{
  virtual void doStuff() = 0;
};

IClass& getHiddenClass(const bool& randomCondition);

// foo.cpp
template <unsigned x>
class HiddenClass : public IClass
{
public:
  void doStuff()
  {
    /* some code using x */
  }
};

IClass& getHiddenClass(const bool& randomCondition)
{
  static HiddenClass<42> ifRandomCondition;
  static HiddenClass<9000> ifNotRandomCondition;

  if (randomCondition)
    return ifRandomCondition;
  else
    return ifNotRandomCondition;
}
```

Is it OK are is there a better workaround? This example is simplified and abstract, but I also won't need to store a large number of valid instances.

Comment: How does this prevent me from just creating a `HiddenClass<123>`? And what if I want to create a second `HiddenClass<42>` instance?

Comment: You just don't know HiddenClass exists, do you? It's not mentioned in .hpp file.

Comment: Can you describe what you're doing? That is, what problem you're trying to solve with this approach? It's unorthodox and there may be a better way.

Comment: I'm decoding x86-64 instruction set. The Decoder class is parametrized with three things: CPU operating mode, default operand-size of an instruction, and default address-size of an instruction. The thing is some parameter values don't make sense (basically I support only 5 triplets: (64 bit mode, 4, 8), (compatibility mode, 4, 4), (compatibility mode, 2, 2), (protected mode, 4, 4), (protected mode, 2, 2)). I indeed see this as an unorthodox implementation, but I was going for brevity (ensured by template meta-programming) + speed (since my compiler basically generates 5 different decoders).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `static_assert` to prevent invalid instantiation, available in C++11.

I don't understand the purpose of your "hidden class". Interfaces are meant to do exactly this - to hide the implementation from users and only let them have a predefined set of operations that they can use. Declare your interface in a separate header file and share it with user. Inherit your concrete class from the interface (in another, non-shared header file) and implement it in cpp file (again, non-shared).

Comment: Great feature, thanks! Seems like that would prevent anyone to make an invalid class instantiation. But I would also like to completely hide HiddenClass from user, so one would be aware of IClass only (I believe it would reduce confusion and ease code re-using).

Answer (score 1):

That's legitimate as far as it goes.  You might also try parameterizing the class by an enum instead, which you'd then case on inside the class.  That might be more or less readable than what you've posted, depending on the details of your situation.

Comment: You mean like `template <bool cond>` and then inside `doStuff` `x = cond ? 42 : 9000`? Haven't thought about it, thank you!